# Extract letters and numbers in specific positions from a mixed string

Tags: r, regex

```
df
   Chromosome aaChange
1          16 p.E548fs
2          16   p.S64X
3          16   p.P23H
4          16   p.G18V
5          16  p.L251S
```

I want to extract the third letter and the numbers followed. Below is the output I want.

```
   Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
 1         16 p.E548fs             E548
 2         16   p.S64X              S64
 3         16   p.P23H              P23
 4         16   p.G18V              G18
 5         16  p.L251S             L251
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you want to match seems to be quite straightforward: it always starts with a capital letter and is followed immediately by a series of one or more digits. This gives the pattern `[A-Z]\\d+`. We can input it into `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
df$Protein_position <- str_extract(df$aaChange, "[A-Z]\\d+")
  Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
1         16 p.E548fs             E548
2         16   p.S64X              S64
3         16   p.P23H              P23
4         16   p.G18V              G18
5         16  p.L251S             L251
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sub` in base R :

```
transform(df, Protein_position = sub('..(.\\d+).*', '\\1', aaChange))

#  Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
#1         16 p.E548fs             E548
#2         16   p.S64X              S64
#3         16   p.P23H              P23
#4         16   p.G18V              G18
#5         16  p.L251S             L251
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Chromosome = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), 
aaChange = c("p.E548fs", "p.S64X", "p.P23H", "p.G18V", "p.L251S")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked well for me. How to understand '\\1' here?

Comment: `\\1` is used to return the captured expression (`(....)`) in pattern. So here we are capturing third character followed by digits.

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(Protein_position = str_replace(aaChange,
      '^[^.]+\\.(.*)[^0-9]+$', '\\1'))
```

-output

```
#  Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
#1         16 p.E548fs            E548f
#2         16   p.S64X              S64
#3         16   p.P23H              P23
#4         16   p.G18V              G18
#5         16  p.L251S             L251
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Chromosome = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), 
aaChange = c("p.E548fs", "p.S64X", "p.P23H", "p.G18V", "p.L251S")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```